# Forming and soving a Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, word-problem

A customer goes to a bank to withdraw money using cheque. The cashier interchanges the rupee figure and paise figure and in the process pays 1.51 rupee more than twice the amount on the cheque. What was the original amount on the cheque

My solution goes like assuming the rupee figure to be x and paise figure to be y then -
x + (y/100)= 1.51+ 2(y+(x/100)) but i am not rly sure if i interpreted it right?
So I would be grateful for any help with it .

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$=rupee and $p$=paise

\begin{align*}
p+0.01r&= 2(r+0.01p)+1.51\\
100p+r&= 200r+2p+151\\
98 p &= 199 r + 151\\
p &= 199 n + 32\\
 r &= 98 n + 15\\
 n &\in\mathbb{ Z}
\end{align*}

solutions are revealed by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+100p%2Br%3D+200r%2B2p%2B151+over+integers)
but this only works for currency if $n=0$